# I need a service to send me an email if someone registered on my API registration form

Tags: forms, api, email, registration

I have a website which provides API service by the registration form, so I need a system to integrate it in the registration form to receive an email if someone registered on the API service. (I need this service to be available to be ready for integration or connection with other systems).

Comment: what server are you using and what language is available on that server?

Comment: @User23332 the server  is cloudflare the website is in PHP

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you PHPMailer

Examples

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples

Documentation

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/docs

Github project

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: thank you for your response, but is there any free service provide the PHPMailer integration to integrate it automatically in my website?.

Comment: typically PHPMailer can be integrated using less than 10 lines of code